# Solr query return part of filed content

Tags: solr, solrj

I use Solr to index my blog, and an article may have tens of thousands of words. so when I do a query, the response may like this

```
"response": {
        "numFound": 4,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "content": ["abc........"], //the whole article may have 10000 words
                "_id": "5d48f6d598b89e22d07629a0",
                "_version_": 1642371362640101376
            },
            ....
        ]
    }
```

there's no need to return the whole article in the search page. so it is possible to return the first 100 words of the article?

Comment: Usually you want to [use Highlighting for that](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/highlighting.html), as it returns the text surrounding the actual hit (which is what search engines usually show you). Would that work?

Comment: right, but when I want to list the all articles `select?q=*:*` the highlighting is empty

Comment: `hl.defaultSummary=true` might give you what you want in that case - "If true, use the leading portion of the text as a snippet if a proper highlighted snippet can’t otherwise be generated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are currently storing the whole article, but want to just return a first para or so.

The easiest way to do so is to mark your **content** field as index only (stored=false) and clone it to a separate (indexed=false) field that will return what you want.

You cannot do so during indexing, but you can do it with [UpdateRequestProcessors pipeline](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/update-request-processors.html).

So you would use

1. CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory
2. Truncate?

The challenge is actually to truncate to 100 **words** as that is surprisingly hard to define in language-neutral fashion (and what about punctuation?). If you are happy to truncate by characters, then you can do that with **TruncateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory**. But if you insist, it has to be words, you could look into **RegexReplaceProcessorFactory** and define regular expression that matches that.

Comment: great, you remind me that I don't need to store `content` field just clone it. so I use [Copying Fields](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/copying-fields.html) like this `<copyField source="content" dest="part_content" maxChars="100"/>` , now I use `part_content` field instead of `content` as search result